# How do I compile files linked with llvm-link and pass my customized libraries and compiler pass to clang?

Tags: c++, c, clang, llvm

Right now I am using the following line:
 `clang -Xclang -load -Xclang ../pass/pass.so  -O2 -I../library/src/include/ -L../library/src/debug/ -DTAG_BITS=15 -lib1 -lib2 example.ll -o example`

where I'm using my pass and `example.ll` is an example file that I linked with a runtime file (needed by the pass) using `llvm-link`. It does compile, but clang is skipping the libraries and using the built-ins instead:

`clang: argument unused during compilation: '-I ../library/src/include/' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]`

Why is the library being skipped? If I'm doing this wrong is there some other way I could compile the linked modules?

Answer (score 0):

You've asked clang to compile `example.ll` which is an LLVM IR text file, and no other files. LLVM IR text doesn't have C-style `#include` statements, so the `-I` flag telling clang to look in your `../library/src/include/` directory to resolve files in a `#include` directive can't affect the compilation.